# Why are underscores better than hyphens for file names?

Tags: python, naming

From [Building Skills in Python](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python/BuildingSkillsinPython.pdf):

> A file name like `exercise_1.py` is better than the name `exercise-1.py`. We can run both programs equally well from the command line, but the name with the hyphen limits our ability to write larger and more sophisticated programs.

Why is this?

Comment: Incidently, the author of that particular document is one of the top-ranking Python answerers on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott

Comment: Related discussion on SuperUser: [Using underscore in file names vs dashes?](https://superuser.com/q/266491/654416).

Comment: This is a good read as well, on Unix & Linux: [Good style/practices for separators in file (or directory) names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44153/201820)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The issue here is that importing files with the [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) (the default keyboard key <kbd>-</kbd>; `U+002D`) in their name doesn't work since it represents minus signs in Python. So, if you had your own module you wanted to import, it shouldn't have a hyphen in its name:

```
>>> import test-1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import test-1
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import test_1
>>>
```

Larger programs tend to be logically separated into many different modules, hence the quote

> the name with the hyphen limits our ability to write larger and more sophisticated programs.

Answer (score 24):

From that very document (p.368, Section 30.2 'Module Definition'):

> Note that a module name must be a valid Python name... A module's name is limited to letters, digits and "_"s.

Comment: ... which is about three hundred pages away from the text saying not to use hyphens.

Comment: good observation, but as Glenn said, don't think we can blame people for not connecting those two quotes without help.